# Couldn't build application native image with GraalVM

Tags: linux, docker, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have built an API in Micronaut and trying to deploy in it GCP Cloud Run as a native graalVM image

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
# Stage 1: Build the JAR
FROM gradle:jdk11 as gradle
COPY --chown=gradle . /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN gradle assemble --no-daemon

# Stage 2: Build the native image
FROM ghcr.io/graalvm/graalvm-ce:latest as graalvm
RUN \
    # Install GraalVM Native Image
    gu install native-image;
COPY --from=gradle /home/app/build/libs/greetings-cloud-run-0.1-all.jar /home/app/server.jar
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN native-image -H:Name=greetings-cloud-run --no-server -cp server.jar com.arun.Application


# Stage 3: Prepare Server
FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc
RUN apk update && apk add libstdc++
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=graalvm /home/app/greetings-cloud-run .
ENTRYPOINT ["./greetings-cloud-run"]
```

I checked till Stage-2 and the native image is running perfectly fine. I included Stage-3 to run my native-image and ending up with below error

```
$ docker run a/micro                                                                                                                                  
./greetings-cloud-run: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./greetings-cloud-run)
./greetings-cloud-run: Relink `/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1' with `/usr/glibc-compat/lib/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `memset'
```

Need help on how to run my Native image

Comment: You could try using the [Red Hat distoless UBI for quarkus-native](https://quay.io/repository/quarkus/quarkus-distroless-image?tag=latest&tab=tags) if you are willing to switch base images.

Comment: Thanks .. mine is based out of Micronaut not quarkus

Comment: This should not matter.

Comment: ah ok. so you mean, i can just have this image for my stage-3 ?

Comment: Yes. The `RUN apk ...` can be removed and instead, one could add `USER nonroot` (see [quarkus documentation on distoless base images](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image#using-a-distroless-base-image)). Rest should work as-is.

Comment: sure. Thanks. am just trying to understand how to implement your above suggestion in my dockerFile ..

Comment: I just removed the stage-3 and added `EXPOSE 8080 ENTRYPOINT ["./greetings-cloud-run"]` in stage-2 itself

Comment: This has the implication that you are using a relatively fat base-image (`>= 500 MB`) compared to a distorless base image (`~10 MB`).

Comment: The native image isn't running in plain-linux.. :( some or the other error it keeps throwing

Comment: That's.... unfortunate. You could try compiling the native executable with statically linked libraries and see if this helps. This will however, increate execution time of the native image compilation and the size of the generated binary.

Answer (score 0):

It should be standard thing in Micronaut docs,

try https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-creating-first-graal-app-maven-java.html

> 5.2. Creating native image inside Docker
> The output following this approach is a Docker image that runs the native image of your application. You don’t need to install any additional dependencies.

> Building GraalVM native image with Maven
> `$ ./mvnw package -Dpackaging=docker-native`

Comment: Do we have a documentation for what docker image is used as base for this build?

Comment: Check maven/gradle plugin docs or sources

Comment: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-maven-plugin/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this error today. As explained in [this gitter thread](https://gitter.im/micronautfw/questions?at=600f03213855dd07fd79898f), the problem is due to not pinning the version of the `frolvlad/alpine-glibc` docker image. Looks like the newer versions of `frolvlad/alpine-glibc` are based on alpine 3.13 or newer and those are the versions where this error occurs. Changing `frolvlad/alpine-glibc` to `frolvlad/alpine-glibc:alpine-3.12` fixed it for me